# The values of default arguments in python function

Tags: python, arguments

I read the following tutorial:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

and do some experiments.

I found that default argument is very confusing. Could anyone can explain the following phenomenon?

First, I tried following code:

```
Code 1

def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

The results are:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
```

According to the document, this is because that default argument L is mutable and its value will be evaluated only once when the function is defined. That looks good!

However, I tried Code 2 next:

```
Code 2

def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

and the results are:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

To study the default argument, I improved Code 2 and tried Code 3:

```
Code 3

def f(a, L=None):
    print(type(L))
    print(id(L))
    print(L)

    if L is None:
        L = []
        print(id(L))

    L.append(a)
    return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

the results are:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
4381397320
None
4385607368
[1]

<class 'NoneType'>
4381397320
None
4385607496
[2]

<class 'NoneType'>
4381397320
None
4386251464
[3]
```

**This shows that the L that before the if statement is always None and has different id with the id of L that in the if statement, and the former's id is fixed while the latter changes in every run.**

I also tried the following code:

```
L_r = f(5)
print(id(L_r))
```

and the result is:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
4381397320
None
4385607496
4385607496
```

This shows that L_r has the same id as the L in the if statement.

**Can you explain what the difference between L outside the if statement and in the if statement and why?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't give `L`, default arguments will create a variable `L`, and reuse it for your mutiple calls, so in **Code 1**, it is edited in the same `L`.

but in **Code 2**, you change `L` in function:

```
if L is None:
   L = []
```

default parameter `L=None` is always same(id=`4381397320`) as **Code 1**, but this statement make `L` refernce to a new variable, so the `id` will be different, and result will not be accumulated.

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )